# Angucomplete Alt autocomplete getting data in array

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

I am using Angucomplete Alt with Loopback at backend. 'Angucomplete Alt' is expecting object in response while Loopback is providing data in array. How to parse this or convert in correct format. Though I am getting correct data. but my array should be bounded in object.

http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/

Comment: attached fiddle/plunkr with reproducible issue please

Comment: Its on local.

response from API is [{id:1, name:"abc"}, {id:2, name:"abc"}, {id:3, name:"abc"} ] N expected in object form like {xyz:[{id:1, name:"abc"}, {id:2, name:"abc"}, {id:3, name:"abc"}, ]}

Comment: is it jsonp request?

Comment: I don't issue for CORS. Thats clear. How to convert it in object. Issue is that.